# ¿Cómo puedo pasar datos de JavaScript a Python Flask?

Tags: javascript, html, python, flask

necesito pasar una variable que tengo en JavaScript a Python Flask.
Imaginemos que en el código html tengo lo siguiente.

```
<script>
    var nombre = 'Enrique';
</script>
```

Y en python tengo lo siguiente.

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

Necesito almacenar en una variable de python el nombre 'Enrique'
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Normalmente esto se hace por POST o por GET. Envie por parámetro el nombre o el valor y listo.

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez vale, y como lo hago?